# How can I Remove Special Formatting with PowerShell (Tabs, Cariage Enter, BackSpaces, Newlines, and more)

Tags: powershell, tabs, character

[image]

I want to remove these carriage returns (or at least I think that's what they are) using PowerShell but I am having trouble doing so. I've used:

> -replace "`n",""
>
> -replace "`t",""
>
> -replace "`b",""
>
> -replace "`r",""

nothing seems to work. any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be surgical about the deletions, one crude but effective method is to use a .Net ASCII encoding object to get a numeric value of the offending character(s):

```
$text = "Test`n`b`r"
$enc = New-Object System.Text.ASCIIEncoding
$text.ToCharArray() | Foreach-Object { echo "$($_) $($enc.GetBytes($_))" }
```

For every character in a line of your text, that code will output the character and then its numeric value. It will look something like this (characters in parentheses won't appear in the actual output, they're there for clarification):

```
T 84
e 101
s 115
t 116

 10 (`n)
 8  (`b)
 13 (`r)
```

By running it against one line of your CSV file, you should be able to detect what needs to be stripped. You can then perform a replacement by converting the numeric value back into the ASCII character it represents. For instance, both of these statements will delete a `b character from your text:

```
$text -replace "`b",""
$text -replace $enc.GetChars(8),""
```

Answer (score 0):

try using regex:

```
[regex]::Replace("←xxxx←", "←" , "" ) # give xxxx
```

or if values are numbers

```
[regex]::Replace("←356←", "\D" , "" ) # give 356
```